# How to memoization using map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, memoization

Here is my code. It's not work...Anyone can help me?

```
map<int,int> fibo;

int fibonacci( int n )
{
    if ( n == 0 || n == 1 )
        return 1;
    map<int,int>::iterator itr = fibo.find( n );
    if ( itr != fibo.end() )
        return itr->second;
    else
        return fibo[ n ] = fibonacci( n -1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 );
}
```

i've solved this.
[Here's the Sample Solution!](http://pastebin.com/iWwCvea7)

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for `end()` against the wrong container. Presumably, `results` is another instance of a `map<int,int>`.

Change `results` to `fibo`:

```
    if ( itr != fibo.end() )
```

Comment: It was uploade time problems! :)

Comment: You don't describe what you think is wrong. [It seems to work for me after this fix.](http://ideone.com/wjs7rA) If you are going to fix your code using my answer and then say it is still wrong, you have to describe what is wrong.